# How to see trade activity of a stock?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

I would like to see the activity on a stock, for example the buys and sells of a stock, and what they where sold at. It can be delayed of course

Also, this is information that has to be reported.
[In compliance to 92-26 SEC Approval of Trade Reporting for Regular Nasdaq Securities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBMiF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are web sites that provide time and sales data but the amount of data they provide tends to be limited and often time delayed.  For example:

https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/abx/time-sales

A good broker will provide this in real time, streaming live throughout the day.  AFAIK, on the retail side you only see round lots reported.  You may have to spring for subscription data  ($$$) to see all trades, including odd lots (NASDAQ, NYSE, Bloomberg, etc.).